# Uncaught ReferenceError: method is not defined

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I am getting this error in Chrome browser console. My page is using an external js file where the method is defined. Page is recognizing other methods but not recognizing this particular method.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: getBillingAndShipping_AJAX is not defined  at

[image]

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    Method1();Method2();Method3();updatecalender();UpdateItemDetailHeader();getBillingAndShipping_AJAX('0',1,0,0,'','False',''); EnableDisableHeaderInfo_ReviseOrder(false);DisableControlForContractorAndCS(true);HideDeleteForDependentItems();GetTimeDifference();hideinactive('content');$(document).ready(function() {changeoptions_user();if(typeof callAutocomplete!='undefined'){callAutocomplete();}  });$(document).ready(function () {if($.browser.msie) {$('input:radio').css({ border:'none'}); $('input:checkbox').css({ border:'none'});   } });if(typeof js_load!='undefined') js_load();
    var Page_ValidationActive = false;
```

This is my server side script.
I had tried both ScriptManager/ClientScript methods like  RegisterClientScriptBlock and RegisterStartUpScript, but no luck. Please help.

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "Bind Billing Shipping DDL", string.Format("getBillingAndShipping_AJAX('{0}',1,1,{1},'{2}','{3}','{4}');", 
hdnFactoryID1.Value, 
miCustomerType, 
stVendorCode, 
mbIsReviseOrder, 
msEdiId), true);
```

Comment: Why -ve. Any specific reason.

Comment: What if you enter `getBillingAndShipping_AJAX` on the developer tools console, What do you get?

Comment: I got it fixed. But still , I love hear the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all. I got the fix. I moved my js method on the page itself and it got recognized. It was not recognized if it was in js file. I dont know why. Its weird.